# Keep getting the KeyError: ' '

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyerror

I keep getting KeyErrors: ' ' whenever i try to run this code

```
caeser = {
    "A": "N",
    "B": "O",
    "C": "P",
    "D": "Q",
    "E": "R",
    "F": "S",
    "G": "T",
    "H": "U",
    "I": "V",
    "J": "W",
    "K": "X",
    "L": "Y",
    "M": "Z",
    "N": "A",
    "O": "B",
    "P": "C",
    "Q": "D",
    "R": "E",
    "S": "F",
    "T": "G",
    "U": "H",
    "V": "I",
    "W": "J",
    "X": "K",
    "Y": "L",
    "Z": "M",
    "a": "n",
    "b": "o",
    "c": "p",
    "d": "q",
    "e": "r",
    "f": "s",
    "g": "t",
    "h": "u",
    "i": "v",
    "j": "w",
    "k": "x",
    "l": "y",
    "m": "z",
    "n": "a",
    "o": "b",
    "p": "c",
    "q": "d",
    "r": "e",
    "s": "f",
    "t": "g",
    "u": "h",
    "v": "i",
    "w": "j",
    "x": "k",
    "y": "l",
    "z": "m",
    "!": "=",
    "@": "+",
    "#": "-",
    "$": "_",
    "%": ")",
    "^": "(",
    "&": "*",
    "*": "&",
    "(": "^",
    ")": "%",
    "_": "$",
    "-": "#",
    "+": "@",
    "=": "!",
    "1": "7",
    "2": "3",
    "3": "9",
    "4": "6",
    "5": "4",
    "6": "2",
    "7": "1",
    "8": "0",
    "9": "5",
    "0": "8"
}

def en_decrypt(data):
    text = ""
    for i in data:
        n_letter = caeser[i]
        text = text + n_letter
    return text

menu = ""
while menu != "1" or menu != "2":
    menu = input("Would you like to save a new password or view existing ones"
        "\n1. add new password"
        "\n2. View existing passwords"
        "\n3. Exit: ")
    if menu == "1":
        software = input("Enter the name of the software you are using: ")
        username = input("Enter your username for this software: ")
        password = input("Enter your password for this software: ")
        file = open("securePasswordDate.txt", "a")
        file.write(en_decrypt(software) + " | " + en_decrypt(username) + " | " + en_decrypt(password)  + "\n")
        file.close()

    if menu == "2":
        file = open("securePasswordDate.txt", "r")
        for i in file:
            data = i.split("|")
            print("Software: "+ en_decrypt(data[0]) +" | Username: " + en_decrypt(data[1]) + " | Password: "+ en_decrypt(data[2]))

    if menu == "3":
        exit()
```

I have tried everything that i could think of to fix this problem but it keeps accouring
I am trying to encrypt some text using this program and it can encrypt but then whenever i try to view the the text by pressing 2 thats when it throws the error
here is the erron and the trace backs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\bhard\Desktop\password_manager\main.py", line 106, in <module>
    print("Software: "+ en_decrypt(data[0]) +" | Username: " + en_decrypt(data[1]) + " | Password: "+ en_decrypt(data[2]))
  File "c:\Users\bhard\Desktop\password_manager\main.py", line 84, in en_decrypt
    n_letter = caeser[i]
KeyError: ' '
PS C:\Users\bhard\Desktop\password_manager>
```

Comment: `while menu != "1" or menu != "2"` will always be true…

Comment: We don't know what the input file looks like. But if there are two `|` next to eachother, or if `|` is at the start of a line, `i` will be the empty string.

Comment: And I hope you don't use that "encryption" system in a production or real enviroment

Comment: The function `en_decrypt()` uses `caeser` variable, but there isn't any such variable in the scope of the function.

Comment: @teoman `caeser` is a module global variable. Otherwise, the error message would be different.

Comment: @9769953 You are absolutely right, I'm incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

You have a space in your input file, but not in your encoding dict.

Answer (score 0):

A few things to change to you code.

in case you don't have a match in your dictionary, you should return the provided character unchanged (this is what triggers your error)

```
def en_decrypt(data):
    text = ""
    for i in data:
        n_letter = caeser.get(i, i)  # using "get" method
        text = text + n_letter
    return text
```

Then ensure your code will not run infinitely by having a correct condition:

```
menu = "1"
while menu in ["1", "2"]:
```

*Last but lot least, know that this is just a toy code that will give you zero security as it does not rely on a proven cryptography standard ;)*

output:

```
Would you like to save a new password or view existing ones
1. add new password
2. View existing passwords
3. Exit: 1
Enter the name of the software you are using: test
Enter your username for this software: name
Enter your password for this software: abcd

Would you like to save a new password or view existing ones
1. add new password
2. View existing passwords
3. Exit: 2
Software: test  | Username:  name  | Password:  abcd
```